# Getting error in filter initialization in query builder

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, query-builder, jquery-query-builder

I am getting a string like this

```
 "{id: 'breakthrough_designation_y_n',label: 'Breakthrough Designation Y/N',type: 'string',input: 'radio',values:{'Yes': 'Yes','No': 'No'},operators: ['equal']},{id: 'breakthrough_designation_y_n',label: 'Breakthrough Designation Y/N',type: 'string',input: 'radio',values:{'Yes': 'Yes','No': 'No'},operators: ['equal']}";
```

I can also put this in an object like this

```
obj : [ "{id: 'breakthrough_designation_y_n',label: 'Breakthrough Designation Y/N',type: 'string',input: 'radio',values:{'Yes': 'Yes','No': 'No'},operators: ['equal']},{id: 'breakthrough_designation_y_n',label: 'Breakthrough Designation Y/N',type: 'string',input: 'radio',values:{'Yes': 'Yes','No': 'No'},operators: ['equal']}";]
```

Problem is, filter of query builder can't read the value of this object because of those double quotes **(")** after and before square braces **([)**

I just want to remove those double quotes from and object. So filter can read out object properly. So is there any method in javascript or c# to do this ?

My expected output is :

```
obj : [ {id: 'breakthrough_designation_y_n',label: 'Breakthrough Designation Y/N',type: 'string',input: 'radio',values:{'Yes': 'Yes','No': 'No'},operators: ['equal']},{id: 'breakthrough_designation_y_n',label: 'Breakthrough Designation Y/N',type: 'string',input: 'radio',values:{'Yes': 'Yes','No': 'No'},operators: ['equal']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "{id: 'breakthrough_designation_y_n',label: 'Breakthrough Designation Y/N',type: 'string',input: 'radio',values:{'Yes': 'Yes','No': 'No'},operators: ['equal']},{id: 'breakthrough_designation_y_n',label: 'Breakthrough Designation Y/N',type: 'string',input: 'radio',values:{'Yes': 'Yes','No': 'No'},operators: ['equal']}";

let obj = eval('(' + str + ')');
console.log(obj);
```

As a note - the string is weird, usually there are quotes around properties. [See W3 Schools JSON Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Comment: Thanks... but I have tried this method... doesn't work !! And I'm getting this string from the database, which is not in my control...Can you help with another method ?

Comment: In Fiddle it [works](https://jsfiddle.net/x2tzagfn/). Are you sure that this is the string format you get from database?

Comment: Thank you so much... @RandomSlav. It works. All I needed to change from ```eval('(' + str + ')');``` to ```eval('[' + str + ']');```.